# mysql Quiz leaderboard filter by points, time taken

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, grouping

I have a quiz report table which shows a report for every quiz a user takes. I need to create a leaderboard from this, which shows the top users best score, filtering by **points** and then **time taken**.

here is a link to a sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65fbf0/1

I am really struggling as i need to filter the results by two columns for one user, my ideal result would be

```
Results for Quiz id 1
---------------------------------------------------------------   
| user_id  |  points  |  time_spend  |  start_dt  |  quiz_id  |
| 1        |  3       | 0.5          | May,15 2015|  1        |
| 2        |  3       | 0.8          | May,15 2015|  1        |
| 3        |  2       | 0.5          | May,15 2015|  1        |
```

Then a separate query for all quiz's showing the results from the last week

```
Results from all Quizzs
---------------------------------------------------------------   
| user_id  |  points  |  time_spend  |  start_dt  |  quiz_id  |
| 1        |  3       | 0.5          | May,15 2015|  1        |
| 2        |  3       | 0.8          | May,13 2015|  3        |
| 3        |  2       | 0.5          | May,12 2015|  2        |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort on multiple columns like this:

```
select *
from QuizReport
where quiz_id = 1
order by points desc, time_spend asc;

select *
from (
  select *
  from QuizReport
  where start_dt >= subdate(curdate(), 7)
  order by points desc, time_spend asc) a
group by user_id;
```

`group_by user_id` preserves the first row for every user_id. since the inner query sorts rows by score, the outer query will display best row for every user.

Comment: This is brilliant but how can I filter by the users best score, so I would only get one row for each user per quiz

Comment: see updated answer. this `group by` trick only works in mysql though.